# How do I disable cache_money caching for certain ActiveRecord models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, cache-money

I tried doing the `def index(*args); end;` trick within the models I'd like cache_money to ignore, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

commenting out `index()` will only turn off indexes for that object. But the default index by id will still run.

I have it working, but am in the process of getting the fix upstream.
http://github.com/kbrock/cache_money if you want to test it out before hand.
example:

```
class model < ActiveRecord:Base
  is_cache(false)
  #...
end
```

best of luck and let me know how it goes.

Comment: This looks like a good idea, I think it is `is_cached` with a 'd' on the end though.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed Keenan's branch is offline -- I've also made a cache-money fork on GitHub which does not automatically cache every model unless you put "automatic_caching: true" in your memcached.yml
http://github.com/jamiew/cache-money

Just add "is_cached :repository => $cache" explicitly in each model you want to cache.

Unfortunately this isn't generally available as a gem yet, but I'll see about getting my changes into ngmoco-cache-money (official cache-money appears dead)